# dynamic javascript using jquery

Tags: jquery, dynamic

```
<div id="text">some text</div>

<img src="#" onclick="$.function('http://url.com?q=some+text')"/>
```

I want the `q=` to be dynamic using the text in the previous paragraph. I can get the text into a variable

```
var str = $("#text").text();
```

but am struggling to output this dynamically.

---

EDIT:

It's much simpler than I thought, figured out the solution from Darin's answer:

```
  <div id="text"><p>Testing text to speech</p></div>
  <div id="textlink"></div>
  <img src="#" onclick="$.sound.play('http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?q='+ str)" />
<script>
var str = $("#text").text(); 
</script>
```

Just needed to know how to append a variable. Thanks

Comment: what the heck do you want that `onclick` to do?

Comment: Its funny there are 4 answers already but it can only be assumed that we know what OP wants as his question is not clear enough.  Are we really helping him by spamming him with our assumptions? Or should we possibly wait for him to clarify his question and better explain what he is trying to do?

Comment: @JohnHartsock it seems more fun this way ^_^

Comment: I'm creating a text to speech application for disabled students where a request (i.e. the contents of div#text) is sent to google translate using onclick using this method http://goo.gl/Iwqa0 - Thanks for all the responses so far!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lemme shoot in the dark:

```
<img src="#" onclick="window.location.href = 'http://url.com?q=' + encodeURIComponent($('#text').text());" />
```

or if you want to assign this `src` dynamically:

```
<img src="#" id="foo"/>
```

and then:

```
$(function() {
    $('#foo').click(function() {
        window.location.href = 'http://url.com?q=' + encodeURIComponent($("#text").text());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Start of what *I think* you want to do:

```
$('img').click(function(){
    var str = $("#text").text();
    alert('http://url.com?q=' + str);
});
```

Or maayyyyybe:

```
$('img').click(function(){
    var str = $("#text").text();
    window.location = 'http://url.com?q=' + encodeURIComponent(str);
});
```

Or even:

```
$('img').click(function(){
    var str = $("#text").text();
    this.src = 'http://url.com?q=' + encodeURIComponent(str);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/UrDRX/
(works in HTML5 browsers, edit the color code)

And on and on....

Answer (score 1):

Separation of concerns.  In this case you want to keep behavior (javascript) separate from the content (html) and style (css). - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns

So... `onclick="x();"` is not preferred.  Rather:

```
$(document).ready(function(
 $("#buttonId").click(function() { 
    var val = $("#text").text();
    var url = 'http://url.com?q=' + encodeURIComponent(val);

    alert(url); // or window.location or whatever you want to accomplish
 });
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, if you want to use the entire text-content of the paragraph:

```
var str = encodeURIComponent($('#text').text());

$('#linkId').attr('href','http://url.com?q=' + str);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/e4uLJ/2).